# SPARK SQL : How to filter records by multiple colmuns and using groupBy too

Tags: group-by, apache-spark-sql

```
//dataset
 michael,swimming,silve,2016,USA
 usha,running,silver,2014,IND
 lisa,javellin,gold,2014,USA
 michael,swimming,silver,2017,USA
```

Questions --
   1) How many silver medals have been won by the USA in each sport -- and the code throws the error value === is not the member of string

```
   val rdd = sc.textFile("/home/training/mydata/sports.txt")
val text =rdd.map(lines=>lines.split(",")).map(arrays=>arrays(0),arrays(1),arrays(2),arrays(3),arrays(4)).toDF("first_name","sports","medal_type","year","country")

text.filter(text("medal_type")==="silver" && ("country")==="USA" groupBy("year").count().show
```

2) What is the difference between === and == 
When I use filter and select with === with just one condition in it (no && or ||), it shows me the string result and boolean result respectively but when I use select and filter with ==, errors throws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this:

```
text.filter(text("medal_type")==="silver" && text("country")==="USA").groupBy("year").count().show

+----+-----+
|year|count|
+----+-----+
|2017|    1|
+----+-----+
```

Will just answer your first question. (note that there is a typo in silver in first line)

About the second question:

== and === is just a functions in Scala

In spark === is using **equalTo** method which is the equality test
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equalTo-java.lang.Object-

```
   // Scala:
   df.filter( df("colA") === df("colB") )

   // Java
   import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
   df.filter( col("colA").equalTo(col("colB")) );
```

and == is using **euqals** method which just test if two references are the same object.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Notice the return types of each function == (equals) returns boolean while === (equalTo) returns a **Column** of the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ykout. but the second question is not yet clear .please bear with me as I am a newbie and trying to understand from the resources too. and regarding the return type --- df.select($"_c1"==="INDIA") returns boolean whereas df.filter($"_c1"==="INDIA") returns respective columns

Comment: Indeed both select() and filter() returns Dataset<Row> and takes Columns as argument that's why it fails when you use ==
but select does different thing than filter with the given Column as argument.
filter() returns the full rows that matches the condition in given Column while select() returns a Column of the condition results (column of type boolean) for the selected column.
It's just like saying spark.sql("select country == 'IND' from text") for .select(..) 
and spark.sql("select * from country where country == 'IND'") for .filter(..) 
after you register text as temp view.